# Determine the dimension of the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The vectors $a, b, c, d $ form a basis of $ R^4$. Determine the dimension of the
subspace generated by the vectors $a + b, c + d, a + c, b + d$.

I think combined vectors($a+b,c+d,a+c,b+d$) somehow must be dependent, however, I could not prove.

Comment: Take summation of the first two. Then subtract the third. Now recognize the outcome.

Comment: then it gives b+d and b+d and if we subtract them then 0. It means they are dependent. So obviously dimension cant be 4. What about 3 or 2? How can I prove it?

Comment: Let $r,s,t$ be scalars with $r(a+b)+s(c+d)+t(a+c)=0$ and prove that it follows that $r=s=t=0$. This on base of the independency of $a,b,c,d$. Then you have shown that $a+b,c+d,a+c$ are independent.

Comment: Thank you! Now I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally a good way to tackle these problems is to consider the relation:

$$r_1(a+b)+r_2(c+d)+r_3(a+c)+r_4(b+d)=0$$

and see if you can show all the $r_i$'s to be zero. If you can't, you'll be able to identify one or more of those vectors as linear combinations of the others. In this case, the above equation gives:
$$a(r_1+r_3)+b(r_1+r_4)+c(r_2+r_3)+d(r_2+r_4)=0$$

Since $a,b,c,d$ form a basis, they're independent, which means these coefficients $r_1+r_3$, etc. are all zero. That in turn gives you $r_1=-r_3=-r_4=r_2$. Note that you can have $r_1\neq 0$ and still satisfy this condition, i.e. you don't arrive at any contradiction. So assume that $r_1\neq 0$. Plug these back into the first equation:
$$r_1(a+b)+r_1(c+d)-r_1(a+c)=r_1(b+d)
\\\implies b+d=(a+b)+(c+d)-(a+c)$$

This seems really obvious, but I'm just trying to illustrate a general method of tackling such problems where it might not be that obvious. From the above equation you realize that $(b+d)$ is in the span of the other three vectors, so repeat the process with the remaining vectors to see if they're independent! Let
$$s_1(a+b)+s_2(c+d)+s_3(a+c)=0
\\\implies a(s_1+s_3)+bs_1+c(s_2+s_3)+ds_2=0$$

which implies that $s_1+s_3=s_1=s_2+s_3=s_2=0$ again due to independence of $a,b,c,d$. This gives $s_1=s_2=s_3=0$, which implies that $(a+b),(c+d),(a+c)$ are indeed linearly independent and the subspace dimension is $3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Write the vectors as column vectors in the basis $(a,b,c,d)$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&0 \\1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0 \\0&1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and determine the rank of this matrix using row reduction.

Comment: how you find out this matrix?

Comment: Its  columns are simply the coordinates of $a+b$, $c+d$, &c. in the basis $\{a,b,c,d\}$